# How can I wrap existing static constants into an enumeration?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm porting my Minecraft block protections plugin from Bukkit to Sponge so I can add mods with SpongeForge. Bukkit uses a Material enum to identify all the valid block types in the game. All my protections are specified in the config.yml file like this:

```
CHEST:
  Price: 0.75
  InteractMember: R
  ...
```

With an enum it was very easy to take the keyname in the config file, CHEST, and get the actual enum value with Bukkit.getMaterial(String name). Unfortunately, Sponge refuses to use enums anywhere in their code, so their list of block types is a class containing nothing but static final int constants, which I cannot iterate through or retrieve by name. I tried reflection..

```
HashMap<String,Integer> blockTypes = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

for(Field field, BlockTypes.class.getFields())
    blockMap.put(field.getName(), field.getInt(null));
```

But I can only get the int values for the constants. I need the constants themselves to use in the code, and I can't find any way to do that without making my own enum wrapper for the static constants:

```
public enum Blocks {
    ACACIA_FENCE(BlockTypes.ACACIA_FENCE),
    ACACIA_STEPS(BlockTypes.ACACIA_STEPS),
    ...
    YELLOW_FLOWER(BlockTypes.YELLOW_FLOWER);

    private final BlockTypes type;
    Blocks(BlockTypes type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public BlockTypes getType() { return type; }
    public static BlockTypes getByName(String name) {
        // retrieve enum by name
    }
}
```

Am I really stuck doing this or is there another way I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sponge doesn't use enums for a reason: since you can add other mods, constants would have to be dynamically added (which isn't possible), and assuming blocks in the vanilla game are the only blocks isn't valid.  Support for other mods is one of the main goals of the sponge API.

If your goal is to get a list of all valid `BlockType`s in the game, you should use the `GameRegistry`:

```java
// Getting a list of all types
Collection<BlockType> types = Sponge.getRegistry().getAllOf(BlockType.class)
for (BlockType type : types) {
    System.out.println(type.getName());
}

// Getting a single type by name
Optional<BlockType> type = Sponge.getRegistry().getType(BlockType.class, "minecraft:chest");
if (!type.isPresent()) {
    // show some error, as the given type doesn't exist
} else {
    return type.get();
}
```

You should be able to use `BlockType` as a key in a map, or alternatively the `String` id.  You shouldn't need to make an enum for it (and can't do it automatically).

Worth noting that you're using reflection wrong in your example as well, but I don't think it's too important to explain how it needs to be used right now as that's the wrong approach.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I didn't realize the relationship between the BlockType and BlockTypes class. I also didn't know how the CatalogType interface worked but now I do! Still very new to Sponge and I've got quite a bit more to learn. I do see how this method of cataloging block is much more flexible than using an enum. And yes the reflection code was very poor I just threw it together trying to get something to work.